# Exoplayer ui split the screen and add double tap to go forward/backward circular effect

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, exoplayer

I have to reproduce the following circular effect on the exoplayer.

[image: a busy cat]

I added two views, exo_rew and exo_ffwd.

Which automatically do go back or forward by standard setting.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/exo_rew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        tools:ignore="Orientation" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/exo_ffwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        tools:ignore="Orientation" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/play_pause_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#15ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:played_color="#4589f2"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="2:00:00"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There are two problems that I could not solve:

1) That each view takes half of the screen, exo_rew on the left and exo_ffwd on the right.

I could not find a way to specify in xml a layout_width equal to match_parent/2.
Is there a way?

I tried with weightSum at 1, but it does not seem to work.

2) Create the circular effect as in the image.

the doubts are better to use a canvas creating a circle or a "circle reveal" effect.

Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: try to do a custom circular reveal instead of a full blown circle show a semi circle that gradually grows and subsides, when the double tap happens

Comment: @Paul hey your code is best. did you got the answer for 1. if so please update answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to use ConstraintLayout and add these images with constraint start, end, bottom and top and give them width of 0dp, in this way they'll just occupy the width according to their constraint.
ConstraintLayout is very powerful it will also reduce your view hierarchy. And it would help your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the same double tap behavior like YouTube, you can use my library to achieve it. My basic approach is to override the onTouchEvent of the PlayerView to detect DoubleTapGesture (SimpleGestureDetector) and creating an overlay on top of it.

I've written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173346/how-to-create-youtubes-double-tap-gesture-on-android/57557773#57557773) already. Use the following to implement it:

**0) Requirements:**

- Minimum SDK: 21 (could be lower, but I've not tested older versions yet)
- ExoPlayer2 library (at least 2.10.4) since the replaced view is written above ExoPlayer's PlayerView

**1) Include it to your gradle** (it's hosted on jitpack.io so you've got to add it to your respositories):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.vkay94:DoubleTapPlayerView:0.7.1'
}
```

**2) Add the views inside your XML:**

```
<FrameLayout
    ... >

    <!-- Replace ExoPlayer's PlayerView -->
    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.DoubleTapPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/doubletapplayerview"
        app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_simple_player_view"
        app:use_controller="true"
        ...
    />

    <!-- Other views e.g. ProgressBar etc  -->

    <!-- Add the overlay on top of PlayerView -->
    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.YouTubeDoubleTap
        android:background="@color/dtp_overlay_dim"
        android:id="@+id/youTubeDoubleTap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**3) Set it up inside your activity:**

```
// Link the PlayerView to the overlay to pass increment to the Player (seekTo)
// Important: set the (Simple)ExoPlayer to the PlayerView before this call
youTubeDoubleTap
    .setPlayer(doubletapplayerview)
    .setForwardRewindIncrementMs(5000)

// Set YouTube overlay to the PlayerView and double tapping enabled (false by default)
doubletapplayerview
    .activateDoubleTap(true)
    .setDoubleTapDelay(500)
    .setDoubleTapListener(youTubeDoubleTap)
  //.setDoubleTapListener(this) => handle event directly within´the activity
```

[Link to the library on Github](https://github.com/vkay94/DoubleTapPlayerView)

Comment: Congratulations on your library, the main problem was the regular creation of circles without causing problems with the different screen formats from the device to the tablet.
Do you by chance have a video or a gif to see how it all really works?

Comment: Hey ;) I recorded a video right now: https://youtu.be/DVhdPdh62O0 About the circles: To overcome the problem you refer I saved a dimen (the basic approach is to cut parts from the oval) into different values folders (different screen widths) and apply this value to the circle drawables. Currently, the lib has a default value and one for w600dp. In Android Studio, it looks fine for different devices ;)

Comment: I don't know if I noticed it at the second 0:05 and at 0:13, what happens on the right, take a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhlHW.png
Nothing seems to happen on the left.
I'm talking about the white line that we have.
This I created it: bit.ly/2Gd8S1S
based on exoplayer, I modified the classic graphics and added additional features, subtitles, change time and etc.
It would be very interesting for me to know your opinion about it.

Comment: Ah right, this white line, happened on my debug device but no more on my actual app (release build) which implements my library, so I forgot about it ^^. The problem was the ripple effect and the drawable itself. Should be fixed now (release 0.4.1) ;). Your app: Looks good (is it fluid? When I tried BottomSheet with ExoPlayer, the video playback stuck for a moment while creating - not really noticable, but as a developer you see it always .D). BTW, is white not a little bit too bright? ;)

Comment: You could release an example of apk so I do a test right now without having to create a project on Android.  It seems to me that problems did not give me fluidity, but I would not be wrong not to use that project for a long time.  Is there a way to contact you privately, to be able to talk to them there?  Twitter, Facebook or email?

Comment: I've added the apk to the assets (release tab) :) What kind of support do you need?

Comment: I felt compliments seems to work well, but you didn't put the central loading in the middle that appears when it's done back and forth.  I thought I would add this functionality to the player that I had created what I showed you, and maybe add something else.  Would you be interested in working together to create one together?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "central loading in the middle that appears when it's done back and forth" (the player controls layout? Play, pause, rewind, etc?)) - I tried to mimic the YouTube behavior as good as I could ;). This YouTube overlay is independent from the controller view. I'd like to keep the library separated. The steps to add this feature are pretty simple and the PlayerView has the same functionalities as the official from Google besides it reacts to double taps if set to true (onTouchEvent is overridden in my implementation).

Comment: @Vkay why we need minimum support version is 21? can i use your library in 16 version?

Comment: or is there any solutions to use your library in sdk 16. Actually in my project i have minimum support version is 16.

Comment: @ShafqatKamal I've chosen 21 as minimum because I though it would be fine (there are only a few devices running below 21) and I wanted to use some features of higher versions, but I discarded an idea I had in mind (I didn't like using many drawables for the animation ...). I'll release a patch today which reduces the level to 16 and updates the dependencies ;)

Comment: ok please release a version which have minimum support version 16. I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: I've already released it yesterday, the version is now 0.7.1 (=> https://github.com/vkay94/DoubleTapPlayerView/releases/tag/0.7.1) ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout Like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/exo_rew"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/exo_ffwd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />


</LinearLayout>
```