# How to create youtube's double-tap gesture on Android?

Tags: android, youtube, android-drawable, exoplayer

I have application with exoplayer on Android. I have create youtube's **double-tap gesture** to jump 10 seconds forward or backward with animation! How create this semicircle with ripple effect on double tap?

Like this

[image]

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: Could you post the code somewhere to take a look at it?

Comment: Vkay created own library, https://github.com/vkay94/DoubleTapPlayerView

I don't have any time to check his solution. Write message to him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also wanted to implement such feature, so I wrote it myself to "copy" YouTube's behavior. It's almost the same. You can find the library here including a sample app: https://github.com/vkay94/DoubleTapPlayerView

The instructions are written in the README, but due to Stackoverflow principals:

**0) Requirements:**

- Minimum SDK: 16 (I couldn't test versions below 21 yet)
- ExoPlayer2 library (at least 2.11.7) since the replaced view is written above ExoPlayer's PlayerView)

**1) Include it to your gradle** (it's hosted on jitpack.io so you've got to add it to your respositories):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.vkay94:DoubleTapPlayerView:1.0.0'
}
```

**2) Add the views inside your XML:**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    
    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.DoubleTapPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        
        app:dtpv_controller="@+id/youtube_overlay" />

    <com.github.vkay94.dtpv.youtube.YouTubeOverlay
        android:id="@+id/youtube_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        
        app:yt_playerView="@+id/playerView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**3) Set it up inside your activity:**

```
youtube_overlay
    .performListener(object : YouTubeOverlay.PerformListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart() {
            // Do UI changes when circle scaling animation starts (e.g. hide controller views)
            youtube_overlay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd() {
            // Do UI changes when circle scaling animation starts (e.g. show controller views)
            youtube_overlay.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    })
    // Uncomment this line if you haven't set yt_playerView in XML
    // .playerView(playerView)

// Uncomment this line if you haven't set dtpv_controller in XML 
// playerView.controller(youtube_overlay)

// Call this method whenever the player is released and recreated
youtube_overlay.player(simpleExoPlayer)
```

Comment: Dont use this library. its crashing in below 21 version.

Comment: @ShafqatKamal It's not surprising since the minimum API Level is 21 (see Requirements). There are probably less than 3% of devices which run older versions.

Comment: Please tell me what's the purpose of this line         app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_simple_player_view"

Comment: Also i am getting one crash from my users please see the screenshot for your better understanding 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fzro1jeuu0vp6d/Screen%20Shot%201441-11-28%20at%202.53.03%20AM.png

Comment: Also i am getting 1 crash and i have firebase report. Please see the screenshot for your better understanding 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqiqsuoe4ypqxte/Screen%20Shot%201441-11-28%20at%202.56.51%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: @ShafqatKamal This attribute is an ExoPlayer attribute which inflates a custom layout.  See here for reference: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html. The error occurs because the layout file doesn't exist in res/layout. You can remove this line if you use the default controller implementation by ExoPlayer :)

Comment: In your latest library version 0.7.1 don't have this functionality may be you deleted this class in your latest version.

youTubeDoubleTap
    .setPlayer(doubletapplayerview)
    .setForwardRewindIncrementMs(5000)

Comment: I've renamed the field to "fastForwardRewindDuration" in this version (increment doesn't fit because you can rewind), but sorry, I haven't updated the post in this regard. Anyway, currently I'm adding more modifications (e.g. changing the speed of the triangles etc => https://imgur.com/1EwanvC). I guess, I'll release it before this weekend, so keep an on the GitHub project's page ;)

Comment: when i update library from 0.6.0 to 0.7.1. Then i found error youTubeDoubleTap class not found. I think you deleted youTubeDoubleTap class in new library verison.

Comment: It's renamed to YouTubeOverlay since 0.7.0. The best way is to follow the Readme from here: https://github.com/vkay94/DoubleTapPlayerView. When I release the new version (probably 1.0.0), I'll update this post according to the changes.

Comment: ok Thank you so much. I am waiting for updating this post.